# Source data types for navigation stack (PointCloud or PointCloud2?)

Tags: ros, navigation, sensor, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have been looking for information about the navigation stack and I am a bit confused. In the "Setup and Configuration of the Navigation Stack on a Robot" tutorial it is said:

> "the "data_type" parameter should be
> set to LaserScan or PointCloud
> depending on which message the topic
> uses"

while in the changelist 1.3 it is said:

> "The navigation stack now supports the
> sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 message which
> should allow it to be used directly
> with many PCL filters and nodelets. As
> a result of this,
> sensor_msgs/PointCloud support becomes
> slightly less efficient because a
> conversion must take place."

Also, I have found some people answering recent questions about data_types saying that they should be either LaserScan or PointCloud, even though the changelist is already a bit old (2010).

I have a velodyne sensor in V-REP that publishes in PointCloud2 so, I am wondering if I can directly add the sensor setting the data_type to PointCloud2 or if I really need to convert the point cloud.

I have tried it, but I get a few errors and I want to discard some options to get it to work.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239503/source-data-types-for-navigation-stack-(pointcloud-or-pointcloud2?)/) by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can set the data_type to PointCloud2.

More information is available in the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles).

---

Originally posted by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) with karma: 146 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thank you! I had missed that wiki.